# How to complete aggregation task with flink cep

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep, flink-sql

I need to count the number of times in a day that A happens and in 15 minutes that B happens。 The stream maybe  A1 ,A2,B1,B2,A3,B3,B4,B5,A4,A5,A6,A7,B6。
In my case the event results are A2,B1   A3,B3     A7,B6。 And I need receive realtime result when the matcher happen。
I've tired something。 I think it can be only true by use flink cep 。But flink-sql-cep not support aggregation. It only calculate event happened。 In this case ,how to accomplish this task with a single SQL.

I tired two step to do it.I use flink sql cep to matcher first，and then sink to kafka.  In step to I souce pre kafka and use over window to aggregation.

first step：
select pins as pin,'first-step' as result_id, cast(order_amount as varchar) as result_value,event_time as result_time
from stra_dtpipeline MATCH_RECOGNIZE 
(   PARTITION BY pin
 ORDER BY event_time 
 MEASURES
 t1.pin as pins,
 '1' as order_amount,
 LOCALTIMESTAMP as event_time
ONE ROW PER MATCH 
AFTER MATCH SKIP to next row
 PATTERN (t1 t2) WITHIN  INTERVAL '30' SECOND
 DEFINE
t1 as t1.act_type='100001' ,
t2 as t2.act_type='100002' )
second step：
    select pin,'job5' as result_id,cast(sum(1) over (PARTITION BY pin,cast(DATE_FORMAT(event_time,'%Y%m%d') as VARCHAR) order by event_time ROWS BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as VARCHAR) as result_value,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as result_time
from stra_dtpipeline_mid
where result_id='first-step' and  DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)=DAYOFMONTH(event_time)

I expect  accomplish this task with a single SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose the two queries into a single query by using either a subquery or a view.

That would be something like

```
SELECT a, b OVER (...) ORDER BY event_time FROM (SELECT x, y MATCH_RECOGNIZE ...) WHERE ...
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW pattern AS SELECT x, y MATCH_RECOGNIZE ...
SELECT ... FROM pattern WHERE ...
```